# Intellij Scala multiple import style formatting settings

Tags: scala, coding-style, formatting, intellij-idea

We have a convention to write

```
import akka.actor.{ Actor, Props }
```

instead of

```
import akk.actor.{Actor, Props}
```

like Intellij formatting function is doing now. But i didn't find such an option in code style settings, are there any ways to change this bahaviour?

Comment: I think the with-spaces style should be the default as it already is in Eclipse (Scala IDE) and Emacs (Ensime).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just created an issue for this, I hope it will be implemented soon, it's simple: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-5471

Answer (score 3):

Preferences > Code style > Scala > Spaces > ☑ Import braces